# Text File to Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, text

I am trying to put my text file into an array..

my text file content is like this:

```
TP-Link|192.168.1.247|CHANNEL 02|warehouse
Ruckus|192.168.1.248|CHANNEL 03|entrance
```

anyone can help me to make the output looks like this:

```
$servers = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'TP-Link',
        'ip' => '192.168.1.247',
        'channel' => 'CHANNEL 02',
        'location' => 'warehouse',
    ),  
    array(
        'name' => 'Ruckus',
        'ip' => '192.168.1.248',
        'channel' => 'CHANNEL 03',
        'location' => 'entrance',
    ),
);
```

thanks in advance..

this is my code:-

```
$file="config/data.txt";

$fopen = fopen($file, r);

$fread = fread($fopen,filesize($file));

fclose($fopen);

$remove = "\n";

$split = explode($remove, $fread);

$servers[] = null;
$tab = "|";

foreach ($split as $string)
{
    $row = explode($tab, $string);
    array_push($servers,$row);
}
```

the problem is it outputs a multidimensional without array names..

and i am not familiar in multidimensional array..

Comment: There's no question here. Please show what you've attempted on this, and ask a specific question.

Comment: i already updated my post.. thanks..

Comment: At least show us how you are reading the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. Check out [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

```
<?php

$servers_array = array();
$handle = @fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");

if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $line = explode("|", $buffer);
        
        $servers_array[] = array(
            "name" => $line[0],
            "ip" => $line[1],
            "channel" => $line[2],
            "location" => $line[3],
        )
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry.. i bet your answer because you make it from my code but i found this one more simpler..

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php

$data = file("your text-file path"); // file() read entire file into array 

// now your array looks like below:-

$array = array('TP-Link|192.168.1.247|CHANNEL 02|warehouse',
'Ruckus|192.168.1.248|CHANNEL 03|entrance'); // comment this array line while using the code

$keys = array('name','ip','channel','location');
$final_array = array();
foreach ($array as $ar){

   $explode = explode('|',$ar);

   $final_array[] = array_combine($keys,$explode);
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/734221

Answer (score 1):

So if you have a text file consisting of the following, just use the following code to get the output that you want:

```
<?php

$str="TP-Link|192.168.1.247|CHANNEL 02|warehouse
Ruckus|192.168.1.248|CHANNEL 03|entrance";

echo '<pre>';
$sections=explode("\n",$str);
print_r($sections);
$finalArray=array();
foreach($sections as $line){
    $finalArray[]=explode("|",$line);
}
print_r($finalArray);

?>
```

NOTE: $str is the text that you get from the text file

Comment: i choose this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42143554/4919083

all works good.. thanks for all of you.. it saves my time..